# I can't compile Bevy in Rust?

Tags: rust, bevy

I am trying to use Bevy to create a game in Rust, but I am experiencing an error when trying to compile my project. The error message I am receiving is:

```
error[E0658]: `let...else` statements are unstable
   --> C:\Users\drew0\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\bevy_render_macros-0.9.0\src\as_bind_group.rs:119:13
```

I have tried following the tutorial on the Bevy website and have also tried removing semicolons, but the error persists. How can I resolve this issue and successfully compile my project using Bevy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`let-else` was stabilized in 1.65. You can run `rustup update` to get the latest version